# How to get one italic Greek letter in math mode when using the upright option with Fourier?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, italic, fourier

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}

\begin{document}
    As $\rho\rightarrow1,000$, we all die.

    \textit{As $\mathit{\rho\rightarrow1,000}$, we all die.}
\end{document}
```

Which generates the following output:

[image]

There is a paragraph in my document that, for reasons that go beyond the post, is typeset in italics and has one Greek letter in math mode in it. Therefore, I'd like to get that Greek letter in italics as well, but I wish to keep the upright option of Fourier, since 99% of Greek letters in my document are in non-italics paragraphs. Can someone help me achieve what I need? Notice that `\mathit{...}` does not work.

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\otherrho` to typeset the non-default shape of the Greek character `\rho`. Since the option `upright` makes `upright` the default shape, the non-default shape picked up by `\otherrho` is `sloped`. Likewise for `\otheralpha`, `\otherbeta`, `\othergamma`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}

\begin{document}
    As $\rho\to1{,}000$, we all die.

\em As $\otherrho\to\mathit{1{,}000}$, we all die.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why `to` instead of `longrightarrow`? Also, which answer is the one that I *should* accept, given that are both correct and identical?

Comment: @Héctor - `\to` involves many fewer characters to type than `\rightarrow`; the macros are otherwise identical. If two or more answers provide (essentially) the same solution -- here, using `\otherrho` to generate a "sloped" `\rho` -- it's customary to accept the one that was posted *first*.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{pseudofourier}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{pseudofourier}{m}{n}{
  <-> futmi
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{pseudofourier}{m}{it}{
  <-> futmii
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{pseudofourier}{b}{n}{
  <-> futmib
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{pseudofourier}{b}{it}{
  <-> futmiib
}{}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\trho}{%
  \text{%
    \fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{pseudofourier}\selectfont
    \symbol{"1A}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

As $\trho\rightarrow1,000$, we all die.

\textit{As $\mathit{\trho\rightarrow1,000}$, we all die.}

\end{document}
```

But this is wrong: symbols should not change their shape according to the context.

[image]

Comment: I suspected I was violating some typographical convention here, but else it looks so ugly to my (untrained) eye...

Comment: This answer comes with egreg's personal seal of disapproval :P

Comment: Is there a circumstance when using `\trho` is superior to using `\otherho`?

Comment: @egreg: Yet I'd love a small caps `Ρ`  in an scshape context… ;o)

Answer (score 5):

Use `\otherrho` to have a slanted Greek letter in  an `upright` setting, and vice-versa. Also I added a pair of braces around the decimal comma to have a correct spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}

\begin{document}
    As $\rho\rightarrow1{,}000$, we all die.

    \textit{As $\mathit{\otherrho\rightarrow1{,}000}$, we all die.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I accept the one it was posted sooner?

Comment: @Héctor: Yes, of course! My answer is not different, except I insisted explicitly on the spacing of the decimal comma, which is unrelated to your question